# Get the name of the directory where a script is executed

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have some script, that uses files in directories around it. It uses

```
dirname $0
```

command.
It should work from any directory where I run this script, but when I run a symbolic link that points to that script I get the path of symbolic link.  So I get the output of dirname rather than the path of the script itself.

Any one know a way to get the path of where the script is run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script: set current working directory to the directory of the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/bash-script-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the real path to your script

```
if [ -L $0 ] ; then
    ME=$(readlink $0)
else
    ME=$0
fi
DIR=$(dirname $ME)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
dirname $(readlink -f $0)
```

Tested with on Ubuntu 14.04:
`which java` returns `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symbolic link.

```
readlink -f `which java`
```

Returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`

Finally,

```
dirname $(readlink -f `which java`)
```

Returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin`, which is the folder under which "java" is located.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, as it's simpler and it works with either a symbolic link or a file.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `realpath` installed:

```
$(dirname $(realpath $0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you, the problem should be the same as the one in: [How do you normalize a file path in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash)

An option not mentioned there is the following python one-liner:

```
python2.6 -c "import os,sys; print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])" "$0"
```

Finally, remember to use double quotes around "$0".

Comment: The answer of jmz is what I need. I little afraid to use you suggestion, because the version of Python at the end of the command name may be different from server to server, and script will less portable.

Comment: Oh that was a typo. Any recent version of python (starting at 2.2) should do, so you can just use "python" instead.