# How to retrieve absolute path given relative

Tags: bash, shell, path, absolute

Is there a command to retrieve the absolute path given a relative path?

For example I want $line to contain the absolute path of each file in dir `./etc/`

```
find ./ -type f | while read line; do
   echo $line
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting relative path into absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045253/converting-relative-path-into-absolute-path) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory).

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file)

Comment: A much better solution than any of the ones listed so far is here [how-to-convert-relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246189/how-to-convert-relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-unix)

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/7032856) for it may be of use to configure paths in your scripts relative to repo path when in a git repo.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

use:

```
find "$(pwd)"/ -type f
```

to get all files or

```
echo "$(pwd)/$line"
```

to display full path (if relative path matters to)

Answer (score 282):

Try `realpath`.

```
~ $ sudo apt-get install realpath  # may already be installed
~ $ realpath .bashrc
/home/username/.bashrc
```

To avoid expanding symlinks, use `realpath -s`.

The answer comes from "[bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file)".

Comment: `realpath` does not seem to be available on the Mac (OS X 10.11 "El Capitan"). :-(

Comment: `realpath` does not seem to be available on CentOS 6 either

Comment: on osx, `brew install coreutils` will bring in `realpath`

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04, `realpath` is already present. I didn't have to install it separately.

Comment: Surprisingly, `realpath` is available on Git for Windows (for me, at least).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-to-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself/246128#246128

Comment: And it has the advantage of allowing you to pass an already absolute path to it. That is... it is idempotent.

Comment: Need a pure bash solution, even if it's 30KLOC.

Comment: Preferable solution is within shell and not requiring external software

Comment: `realpath` now ships with macOS 13 (Ventura), under `/bin`.

Answer (score 145):

If you have the coreutils package installed you can generally use `readlink -f relative_file_name` in order to retrieve the absolute one (with all symlinks resolved)

Comment: The behaviour for this is a little different from what the user asks, it will also follow and resolve recursive symlinks anywhere in the path. You might not want that in some cases.

Comment: @BradPeabody This does work in a Mac if you install coreutils from homebrew `brew install coreutils`. However the executable is prepended by a g: `greadlink -f relative_file_name`

Comment: Notice that the manual page of readlink(1) has as the first sentence of its description: "Note  realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality."

Comment: you can use -e instead of -f to check if the file/directory exists or not

Comment: Completely fails with something as elementary as ".".

Comment: Preferable solution is within shell and not requiring external software

Answer (score 120):

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd)/$(basename "$1")"
```

**UPD** Some explanations

1. This script get relative path as argument `"$1"`
2. Then we get *dirname* part of that path (you can pass either dir or file to this script): `dirname "$1"`
3. Then we `cd "$(dirname "$1")` into this relative dir and get absolute path for it by running `pwd` shell command
4. After that we append *basename* to absolute path: `$(basename "$1")`
5. As final step we `echo` it

Comment: readlink is the simple solution for linux, but this solution works on OSX too, so +1

Comment: This script is not equivalent to what `realpath` or `readlink -f` do. For instance, it doesn't work on paths where the last component is a symlink.

Comment: @josch: The question is not about symlink resolving. But if you want to do that you can provide `-P` option to `pwd` command: `echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"`

Comment: I like the answer, but it only works, if the user is allowed to cd into the directory. This might not always be possible.

Comment: My personal favourite :) Unfortunately, it failed when I fed it "." and ".." as relative paths. Slightly improved version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264222/508355

Comment: `echo "$(cd ${1%/*}; pwd)/${1##*/}"` Some similar with string manipulation if rel path in `$1`.

Comment: Doesn't work correctly with paths that are already absolute.

Comment: Why is this using $1? On my system it largely fails with $1 and gets many of the issues reported in the comments above. If I use $0 it works perfectly for any situation I have tried. This makes sense as $1 is an empty string and $0 contains the path used to start the script

Comment: @MikeKulls: This script expect that you provide parameter. A relative path to somewhere.

Comment: @EugenKonkov ah, makes sense. I was focused on my particular use case, which was to find the path of my own script

Answer (score 39):

For what it's worth, I voted for the answer that was picked, but wanted to share a solution. The downside is, it's Linux only - I spent about 5 minutes trying to find the OSX equivalent before coming to Stack overflow. I'm sure it's out there though.

On Linux you can use `readlink -e` in tandem with `dirname`.

```
$(dirname $(readlink -e ../../../../etc/passwd))
```

yields

```
/etc/
```

And then you use `dirname`'s sister, `basename` to just get
the filename

```
$(basename ../../../../../passwd)
```

yields

```
passwd
```

Put it all together..

```
F=../../../../../etc/passwd
echo "$(dirname $(readlink -e $F))/$(basename $F)"
```

yields

```
/etc/passwd
```

You're safe if you're targeting a directory, `basename` will return nothing
and you'll just end up with double slashes in the final output.

Comment: Excellent entry with `dirname`, `readlink`, and `basename`.  That helped me to get the absolute path of a symbolic link -- not its target.

Comment: Doesn't work when you want to return path to symbolic links (which I just happen to need to do...).

Comment: How could you ever find the absolute path to a path that doesn't exist?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel Quite easily, I would have thought; if I'm in `/home/GKFX` and I type `touch newfile`, then before I press enter you could work out that I mean "create /home/GKFX/newfile", which is an absolute path to a file that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 30):

I think this is the most portable:

```
abspath() {                                               
    cd "$(dirname "$1")"
    printf "%s/%s\n" "$(pwd)" "$(basename "$1")"
    cd "$OLDPWD"
}
```

It will fail if the path does not exist though.

Comment: There's no need to cd back again. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21188136/1504556. Your's is the best answer on this page, IMHO. For those interested the link gives an explanation as to *why* this solution works.

Comment: This is not very portable, `dirname` is a GNU core utility, not common to all unixen I believe.

Comment: @einpoklum `dirname` is a POSIX standard utility, see here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html

Comment: Oh my God, thank you. I've been trying to fix the version that uses `${1##*/}` for a day now, and now that I replaced that trash with `basename "$1"` it seems to finally be properly handling paths that end in /.

Comment: NB, this doesn't do the right thing with a path ending in `../..`

Comment: I [made a version which deals with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59494936/1941213).

Comment: What if `pushd` and `popd`?

Answer (score 18):

`realpath` is probably best

But ...

The initial question was very confused to start with, with an example poorly
related to the question as stated.

The selected answer actually answers the example given, and not at all
the question in the title. The first command is that answer (is it
really ? I doubt), and could do as well without the '/'. And I fail to see
what the second command is doing.

Several issues are mixed :

- changing a relative pathname into an absolute one, whatever it
  denotes, possibly nothing.
  (*Typically, if you issue a command such as `touch foo/bar`, the
  pathname `foo/bar` must exist for you, and possibly be used in
  computation, before the file is actually created.*)
- there may be several absolute pathname that denote the same file
  (or potential file), notably because of symbolic links (symlinks)
  on the path, but possibly for other reasons (a device may be
  mounted twice as read-only). One may or may not want to resolve
  explicity such symlinks.
- getting to the end of a chain of symbolic links to a non-symlink
  file or name. This may or may not yield an absolute path name,
  depending on how it is done. And one may, or may not want to
  resolve it into an absolute pathname.

The command `readlink foo` without option gives an answer only if its
argument `foo` is a symbolic link, and that answer is the value of that
symlink. No other link is followed. The answer may be a relative path:
whatever was the value of the symlink argument.

However, `readlink` has options (-f -e or -m) that will work for all
files, and give one absolute pathname (the one with no symlinks) to
the file actually denoted by the argument.

This works fine for anything that is not a symlink, though one might
desire to use an absolute pathname without resolving the intermediate
symlinks on the path. This is done by the command `realpath -s foo`

In the case of a symlink argument, `readlink` with its options will
again resolve all symlinks on the absolute path to the argument, but
that will also include all symlinks that may be encountered by
following the argument value. You may not want that if you desired an
absolute path to the argument symlink itself, rather than to whatever
it may link to.  Again, if `foo` is a symlink, `realpath -s foo` will
get an absolute path without resolving symlinks, including the one
given as argument.

Without the `-s` option, `realpath` does pretty much the same as
`readlink`, except for simply reading the value of a link, as well as several
other things.  It is just not clear to me why `readlink` has its
options, creating apparently an undesirable redundancy with
`realpath`.

Exploring the web does not say much more, except that there may be
some variations across systems.

Conclusion : `realpath` is the best command to use, with the most
flexibility, at least for the use requested here.

Comment: man page of `readlink`says: "Note realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality."

Comment: @jarno Interesting. My man page does say that, but dates from April 2021. Any idea when that line was included?

Comment: The [commit](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/99deaff7e804298cecc326142bbe7263e2576224) was made in 2017.

Comment: @jarno Thanks. I should learn to search for that kind of info. Well, it is nice to have an answer that gets officially supported after 4 years :-). Too bad there is no badge for that.

Answer (score 17):

My favourite solution was [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605674/508355) by @EugenKonkov because it didn't imply the presence of other utilities (the coreutils package).

But it failed for the relative paths "." and "..", so here is a slightly improved version handling these special cases.

It still fails if the user doesn't have the permission to `cd` into the parent directory of the relative path, though.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Takes a path argument and returns it as an absolute path. 
# No-op if the path is already absolute.
function to-abs-path {
    local target="$1"

    if [ "$target" == "." ]; then
        echo "$(pwd)"
    elif [ "$target" == ".." ]; then
        echo "$(dirname "$(pwd)")"
    else
        echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd)/$(basename "$1")"
    fi
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice!!  But has a bug in this use-case:
to-abs-path /tmp/../tmp/../var
//var

For comparison, the proper expected output would be: 
realpath /tmp/../tmp/../var
/var

Answer (score 9):

Eugen's answer didn't quite work for me but this did:

```
    absolute="$(cd $(dirname \"$file\"); pwd)/$(basename \"$file\")"
```

Side note, your current working directory is unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution, imho, is the one posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373298/9724628.

It does require python to work, but it seems to cover all or most of the edge cases and be very portable solution.

1. With resolving symlinks:

```sh
python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))" path/to/file
```

2. or without it:

```sh
python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))" path/to/file
```

Comment: **The only sane solution.** Unlike `readlink`- and `readpath`-based solutions, some variant of Python is basically guaranteed to be available everywhere – even under edge-case environments like vanilla macOS and the \*BSDs. It's both fascinating and sad that POSIX-compliant shells fail to support this out-of-the-box. Unix: *still imperfect after all these years.*

Answer (score 4):

An improvement to @ernest-a's rather nice version:

```sh
absolute_path() {
    cd "$(dirname "$1")"
    case $(basename $1) in
        ..) echo "$(dirname $(pwd))";;
        .)  echo "$(pwd)";;
        *)  echo "$(pwd)/$(basename $1)";;
    esac
}
```

This deals correctly with the case where the last element of the path is `..`, in which case the `"$(pwd)/$(basename "$1")"` in @ernest-a's answer will come through as `accurate_sub_path/spurious_subdirectory/..`.

Comment: nice try, but: (1) absolute_path /tmp/../tmp/../var
//var
(2) target must exist.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `find`, it's probably easiest to just give the absolute path for it to search in, e.g.:

```
find /etc
find `pwd`/subdir_of_current_dir/ -type f
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bash on Mac OS X which neither has **realpath** existed nor its **readlink** can print the absolute path, you may have choice but to code your own version to print it.
Here is my implementation:

**(pure bash)**

```
abspath(){
  local thePath
  if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^/ ]];then
    thePath="$PWD/$1"
  else
    thePath="$1"
  fi
  echo "$thePath"|(
  IFS=/
  read -a parr
  declare -a outp
  for i in "${parr[@]}";do
    case "$i" in
    ''|.) continue ;;
    ..)
      len=${#outp[@]}
      if ((len==0));then
        continue
      else
        unset outp[$((len-1))] 
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      len=${#outp[@]}
      outp[$len]="$i"
      ;;
    esac
  done
  echo /"${outp[*]}"
)
}
```

**(use gawk)**

```
abspath_gawk() {
    if [[ -n "$1" ]];then
        echo $1|gawk '{
            if(substr($0,1,1) != "/"){
                path = ENVIRON["PWD"]"/"$0
            } else path = $0
            split(path, a, "/")
            n = asorti(a, b,"@ind_num_asc")
            for(i in a){
                if(a[i]=="" || a[i]=="."){
                    delete a[i]
                }
            }
            n = asorti(a, b, "@ind_num_asc")
            m = 0
            while(m!=n){
                m = n
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    if(a[b[i]]==".."){
                        if(b[i-1] in a){
                            delete a[b[i-1]]
                            delete a[b[i]]
                            n = asorti(a, b, "@ind_num_asc")
                            break
                        } else exit 1
                    }
                }
            }
            n = asorti(a, b, "@ind_num_asc")
            if(n==0){
                printf "/"
            } else {
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    printf "/"a[b[i]]
                }
            }
        }'
    fi
}
```

**(pure bsd awk)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
function abspath(path,    i,j,n,a,b,back,out){
  if(substr(path,1,1) != "/"){
    path = ENVIRON["PWD"]"/"path
  }
  split(path, a, "/")
  n = length(a)
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(a[i]==""||a[i]=="."){
      continue
    }
    a[++j]=a[i]
  }
  for(i=j+1;i<=n;i++){
    delete a[i]
  }
  j=0
  for(i=length(a);i>=1;i--){
    if(back==0){
      if(a[i]==".."){
        back++
        continue
      } else {
        b[++j]=a[i]
      }
    } else {
      if(a[i]==".."){
        back++
        continue
      } else {
        back--
        continue
      }
    }
  }
  if(length(b)==0){
    return "/"
  } else {
    for(i=length(b);i>=1;i--){
      out=out"/"b[i]
    }
    return out
  }
}

BEGIN{
  if(ARGC>1){
    for(k=1;k<ARGC;k++){
      print abspath(ARGV[k])
    }
    exit
  }
}
{
  print abspath($0)
}
```

example:

```
$ abspath I/am/.//..//the/./god/../of///.././war
/Users/leon/I/the/war
```

Comment: readlink can handle missing files/folders just file: readlink -m I/am/.//..//the/./god/../of///.././war   Yields same (as yours) output:
/home/dmitry/I/the/war

Answer (score 3):

I found [Eugen Konkov's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175264/how-to-retrieve-absolute-path-given-relative/31605674#31605674) answer to be the best as it doesn't require installing any program. However, it will fail for non-existent directories.

I wrote a function that works for non-existent directories:

```
function getRealPath()
{
    local -i traversals=0
    currentDir="$1"
    basename=''
    while :; do
        [[ "$currentDir" == '.' ]] && { echo "$1"; return 1; }
        [[ $traversals -eq 0 ]] && pwd=$(cd "$currentDir" 2>&1 && pwd) && { echo "$pwd/$basename"; return 0; }
        currentBasename="$(basename "$currentDir")"
        currentDir="$(dirname "$currentDir")"
        [[ "$currentBasename" == '..' ]] && (( ++traversals )) || { [[ traversals -gt 0 ]] && (( traversals-- )) || basename="$currentBasename/$basename"; }
    done
}
```

It solves the problem of non-existent directories by traversing up with `dirname` until `cd` succeeds, then returning the current directory plus everything that was removed by `dirname`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @ernest-a's answer but without affecting `$OLDPWD` or define a new function you could fire a subshell `(cd <path>; pwd)`

```
$ pwd
/etc/apache2
$ cd ../cups 
$ cd -
/etc/apache2
$ (cd ~/..; pwd)
/Users
$ cd -
/etc/cups
```

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find a solution that was neatly portable between Mac OS Catalina, Ubuntu 16 and Centos 7, so I decided to do it with python inline and it worked well for my bash scripts.

```
to_abs_path() {
  python -c "import os; print os.path.abspath('$1')"
}

to_abs_path "/some_path/../secrets"
```

Answer (score 2):

[**BLUF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLUF_(communication)):

```
cd $relative_path ; pwd
```

Here is an explanation that is POSIX compliant (I think), so it should work on any platform.

This is scriptable, of course, but I think breaking it down might make it easier for some people to understand / modify to a particular use case.

You can use `which`, `locate`, `find`, full paths, whatever.

**x=your_file_name**

```
$ x="nvi"
```

`file` easily indicates symlinks

```
$ file -h `which $x`
/usr/local/bin/nvi: symbolic link to ../Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin/nvi
```

Next, munge the output a bit so we get a "complete" relative path.
We just need to remove the middle part in this example.

Note UPPERCASE Y vs lowercase x.  There is probably a cleaner way to do this.

```
$ Y=$(file -h `which $x` | sed "s/$x: symbolic link to //")


$ echo $Y
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin/nvi
```

Using `dirname` we get just the path portion.  `cd` to it and the name should clean itself up.

```
$ cd `dirname $Y` ; pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin
```

That leads us to the old UNIX trick to "ghost walk" a directory by doing it all in parenthesis / a sub-shell.  This effectively returns us to our current directory when done.

We can stick the actual file name back on the end for completeness.

`ls` even makes sure the absolute path is valid, for bonus points.

```
$ ( cd `dirname ${Y}` ; ls `pwd`/${x} )
/usr/local/Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin/nvi
```

So `/usr/local/bin/nvi` is really `/usr/local/Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin/nvi`

Simplified example to quickly "convert" a path:

```
$ (cd /usr/local/bin/../Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin ; pwd)
/usr/local/Cellar/nvi/1.81.6_5/bin
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html

Answer (score 1):

What they said, except `find $PWD` or (in bash) `find ~+` is a bit more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If the relative path is a directory path, then try mine, should be the best:

```
absPath=$(pushd ../SOME_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_Directory > /dev/null && pwd && popd > /dev/null)

echo $absPath
```

Comment: This solution only works for bash, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193087/712014

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "mydir/doc/ mydir/usoe ./mydir/usm" |  awk '{ split($0,array," "); for(i in array){ system("cd "array[i]" && echo $PWD") } }'
```

In the snippet above awk is used to split the string of directories received from echo (via the pipeline) and creates an array.

Here is a step-by-step list of what is happening:

- Space delimited list of directories is piped to awk
- awk splits piped text into an array by spaces
- awk loops over each item in the array (variable i)
- awk uses the awk system command to run a cli command
- The CLI command changes directory (cd) to the path specified by item "i" in the array and then prints (echo) the working directory using the environment variable $PWD"

Using cd to travel to each directory and then print the value of $PWD is a great way to have the OS do the work of determining an absolute path

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash string substitution for any relative path $line:

```
line=$(echo ${line/#..\//`cd ..; pwd`\/})
line=$(echo ${line/#.\//`pwd`\/})
echo $line
```

The basic front-of-string substitution follows the formula
*${string/#substring/replacement}*
which is discussed well here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

The `\` character negates the `/` when we want it to be part of the string that we find/replace.

Comment: Note that you could just use `dirname` & `basename`, I think. Something like `dir=\`dirname $line\`; file=\`basename $line\`; line=\`cd $dir; pwd\`/$file`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather short function that can be used to fully absolutize and canonicalize any given input path using only POSIX shell and `readlink` semantics:

```sh
canonicalize_path() {
    (
        FILEPATH="$1"
        for _ in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;  # Maximum symlink recursion depth
        do
            cd -L "`case "${FILEPATH}" in */*) echo "${FILEPATH%/*}";; *) echo ".";; esac`/"  # cd $(dirname)
            if ! FILEPATH="$(readlink "${FILEPATH##*/}" || ( echo "${FILEPATH##*/}" && false ) )";
            then
                break
            fi
        done
        cd -P "." || return $?
        echo "$(pwd)/${FILEPATH}"
    )
}
```

If the referenced file does not exist only the directory path leading up to the final filename will be resolved. If the any of the directories leading up to the file path does not exist a `cd` error will be returned. This happens to be the exact semantics of the GNU/Linux `readlink -f` command it tries to mimic.

In bash/zsh you can also compact the list of numbers to just `{1..8}` or similar. The number of 8 was chosen as this was maximum limit in Linux for many years before the changed it a total limit of 40 resolution for the entire path in version 4.2. If the resolution limit is reached the code will not fail, but instead return last considered path instead – an explicit `[ -L "${FILEPATH}" ]` check could be added to detect this condition however.

This code can also be easily reused for ensuring the current working directory matches the executed script's location in the filesystem (a common requirement for shell scripts), by simply removing the function and subshell wrapper:

```sh
FILEPATH="$0"
for _ in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;  # Maximum symlink recursion depth
do
    cd -L "`case "${FILEPATH}" in */*) echo "${FILEPATH%/*}";; *) echo ".";; esac`/"  # cd $(dirname)
    if ! FILEPATH="$(readlink "${FILEPATH##*/}" || ( echo "${FILEPATH##*/}" && false ) )";
    then
        break
    fi
done
cd -P "."
FILEPATH="$(pwd)/${FILEPATH}"
```

Answer (score 1):

An update on previous answer using python 3

```
to_abs_path() {
  python -c "import os; print (os.path.abspath('$1'))"
}
```

Allowing

```
to_abs_path "./../some_file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform a variable containing a relative path into an absolute one, this works :

```
   dir=`cd "$dir"`
```

"cd" echoes without changing the working directory, because executed here in a sub-shell.

Comment: On bash-4.3-p46, this doesn’t work: the shell prints an empty line when I run `dir=\`cd ".."\` && echo $dir`

Answer (score 0):

This is a chained solution from all others, for example, when `realpath` fails, either because it is not installed or because it exits with error code, then, the next solution is attempted until it get the path right.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function getabsolutepath() {
    local target;
    local changedir;
    local basedir;
    local firstattempt;

    target="${1}";
    if [ "$target" == "." ];
    then
        printf "%s" "$(pwd)";

    elif [ "$target" == ".." ];
    then
        printf "%s" "$(dirname "$(pwd)")";

    else
        changedir="$(dirname "${target}")" && basedir="$(basename "${target}")" && firstattempt="$(cd "${changedir}" && pwd)" && printf "%s/%s" "${firstattempt}" "${basedir}" && return 0;
        firstattempt="$(readlink -f "${target}")" && printf "%s" "${firstattempt}" && return 0;
        firstattempt="$(realpath "${target}")" && printf "%s" "${firstattempt}" && return 0;

        # If everything fails... TRHOW PYTHON ON IT!!!
        local fullpath;
        local pythoninterpreter;
        local pythonexecutables;
        local pythonlocations;

        pythoninterpreter="python";
        declare -a pythonlocations=("/usr/bin" "/bin");
        declare -a pythonexecutables=("python" "python2" "python3");

        for path in "${pythonlocations[@]}";
        do
            for executable in "${pythonexecutables[@]}";
            do
                fullpath="${path}/${executable}";

                if [[ -f "${fullpath}" ]];
                then
                    # printf "Found ${fullpath}\\n";
                    pythoninterpreter="${fullpath}";
                    break;
                fi;
            done;

            if [[ "${pythoninterpreter}" != "python" ]];
            then
                # printf "Breaking... ${pythoninterpreter}\\n"
                break;
            fi;
        done;

        firstattempt="$(${pythoninterpreter} -c "import os, sys; print( os.path.abspath( sys.argv[1] ) );" "${target}")" && printf "%s" "${firstattempt}" && return 0;
        # printf "Error: Could not determine the absolute path!\\n";
        return 1;
    fi
}

printf "\\nResults:\\n%s\\nExit: %s\\n" "$(getabsolutepath "./asdfasdf/ asdfasdf")" "${?}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605674/12854372) by [@EugenKonkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632019/eugen-konkov) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264222/12854372) by [@HashChange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508355/hashchange), my answer combines the brevity of the former with the handling of `.` and `..` of the latter.  I believe that all the options below rely upon nothing more than the basic [Shell Command Language POSIX standards](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

Using `dirname` and `basename`, an option is:

```
absPathDirname()
{
    [ -d "${1}" ] && set -- "${1}" || set -- "`dirname "${1}"`" "/`basename "${1}"`"
    echo "`cd "${1}"; pwd`${2}";
}
```

Without using `dirname` or `basename`, another brief option is:

```
absPathMinusD()
{
    [ -d "${1}" ] && set -- "${1}" || set -- "${1%${1##*/}}" "/${1##*/}"
    echo "`cd "${1:-.}"; pwd`${2}";
}
```

I would recommend one of the two options above, the rest are just for fun...

Grep version:

```
absPathGrep()
{
    echo "`[ "${1##/*}" ] && echo "$1" | grep -Eo '^(.*/)?\.\.($|/)' | { read d && cd "$d"; echo "${PWD}/${1#$d}"; } || echo "$1"`"
}
```

As an interesting example of "what can be done with the shell's limited RegEx":

```
absPathShellReplace()
{
    E="${1##*/}"; D="${E#$E${E#.}}"; DD="${D#$D${D#..}}"
    DIR="${1%$E}${E#$DD}"; FILE="${1#$DIR}"; SEP=${FILE:+/}
    echo "`cd "${DIR:-.}"; pwd`${SEP#$DIR}$FILE"
}
```