# /bin/sh: pushd: not found

Tags: linux

I am doing the following inside a make file

```
pushd %dir_name%
```

and i get the following error

```
/bin/sh : pushd : not found
```

Can someone please tell me why this error is showing up ?
I checked my $PATH variable and it contains /bin so I don't think that is causing a problem.

Comment: It's not complaining about sh, it's complaining it can't find `pushd`. Is pushd in your  `$PATH`?

Comment: Konerak: pushd makes no sense to be in path, it's a bash builtin. The problem being a *bash* builtin, not a POSIX shell one.

Comment: Why did you edit the code out?

Comment: Most likely your distro has moved /bin/sh to /bin/ash rather than /bin/bash. Unless you specifically force your Make to use bash it will use whatever /bin/sh is.

Comment: Same problem would happen in shell script as well if it is executed NOT by bash.

Answer (score 147):

`pushd` is a `bash` enhancement to the POSIX-specified Bourne Shell. `pushd` cannot be easily implemented as a command, because the current working directory is a feature of a process that cannot be changed by child processes. (A hypothetical `pushd` command *might* do the `chdir(2)` call and then start a new shell, but ... it wouldn't be very usable.) `pushd` is a shell builtin, just like `cd`.

So, either change your script to start with `#!/bin/bash` or store the current working directory in a variable, do your work, then change back. Depends if you want a shell script that works on very reduced systems (say, a Debian build server) or if you're fine always requiring `bash`.

Comment: OP says it's run from make. So it would be setting `SHELL = /bin/bash` rather than starting script with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: But setting SHELL will not work in this case, see `test1` in my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193048/bin-sh-pushd-not-found/5193092#5193092.

Comment: @hlovdal: No, indeed it won't be enough.

Comment: Make sure `#!/bin/bash` is the first line of the file.

Comment: Not that anyone cares, but tcsh also supports pushd. :P

Answer (score 39):

add

> SHELL := /bin/bash

at the top of your makefile 
I have found it on another question [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)

Comment: Yeah thanks. Red Hats default to bash however on Debian it's really sh (or some implementation of it). That was my issue.

Answer (score 22):

A workaround for this would be to have a variable get the current working directory.  Then you can cd out of it to do whatever, then when you need it, you can cd back in.

i.e.

```
oldpath=`pwd`
#do whatever your script does
...
...
...
# go back to the dir you wanted to pushd
cd $oldpath
```

Comment: You can also `cd` into the directory you want and afterwards do `cd -`, no need to use that `$oldpath` variable if you won't use `cd` inbetween. The interesting thing about `pushd` is that each time you use it you are pushing a directory into a stack, and afterwards you can go back to the latest one using `popd`, so it makes sense to use it when you are going into more than one directory and want a sure way back.

Comment: If it's just a oneliner, the following may also work `(cd /new_path ; command )`

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Then select `no`.

Comment: This fixed it for me, now I can install UnrealEngine on a Debian OS.

Answer (score 12):

This is because pushd is a builtin function in bash. So it is not related to the PATH variable and also it is not supported by /bin/sh (which is used by default by make. You can change that by setting SHELL (although it will not work directly (test1)).

You can instead run all the commands through `bash -c "..."`. That will make the commands, including pushd/popd, run in a bash environment (test2).

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

test1:
        @echo before
        @pwd
        @pushd /tmp
        @echo in /tmp
        @pwd
        @popd
        @echo after
        @pwd

test2:
        @/bin/bash -c "echo before;\
        pwd; \
        pushd /tmp; \
        echo in /tmp; \
        pwd; \
        popd; \
        echo after; \
        pwd;"
```

When running make test1 and make test2 it gives the following:

```
prompt>make test1
before
/download/2011/03_mar
make: pushd: Command not found
make: *** [test1] Error 127
prompt>make test2
before
/download/2011/03_mar
/tmp /download/2011/03_mar
in /tmp
/tmp
/download/2011/03_mar
after
/download/2011/03_mar
prompt>
```

For test1, even though bash is used as a shell, each command/line in the rule is run by itself, so the pushd command is run in a different shell than the popd.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, I think `tcsh` (and maybe `csh`?) do end their prompt with `> `: `$ tcsh
haig:/> exit
$ csh
haig:/> exit
$ 
`

Comment: Mine does :) Actually my PS1 is `(\u) \h:\w>` but I just stripped it down to a generic string now for the answer. The prompt in DOS is also ending with `>` by default (`$P$G` IIRC), and I like that.

Comment: Set SHELL with := not with =

Comment: Setting "SHELL = /bin/bash" works fine for me, not sure how you got it to not work.

Answer (score 9):

This ought to do the trick:

```
( cd dirname ; pwd ); pwd
```

The parentheses start a new child shell, thus the `cd` changes the directory within the child only, and any command after it within the parentheses will run in that folder. Once you exit the parentheses you are back in wherever you were before..

Answer (score 7):

Your shell (/bin/sh) is trying to find 'pushd'. But it can't find it because 'pushd','popd' and other commands like that are build in bash.

Launch you script using Bash (/bin/bash) instead of Sh like you are doing now, and it will work

Answer (score 7):

here is a method to point

**sh -> bash**

run this command on terminal

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

After this you should see

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

point to /bin/bash (and not to /bin/dash)

[Reference](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Trouble-configuring-petalinux-2013-10-bin-sh-1-pushd-not-found/td-p/399843)

Answer (score 3):

Synthesizing from the other responses: `pushd` is bash-specific and you are make is using another POSIX shell. There is a simple workaround to use separate shell for the part that needs different directory, so just try changing it to:

```
test -z gen || mkdir -p gen \
 && ( cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/genscript > /dev/null \
 && perl genmakefile.pl \
 && mv Makefile ../gen/ ) \
 && echo "" > $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/gen/SvcGenLog
```

(I substituted the long path with a variable expansion. I probably is one in the makefile and it clearly expands to the current directory).

Since you are running it from make, I would probably replace the test with a make rule, too. Just

```
gen/SvcGenLog :
    mkdir -p gen
    cd genscript > /dev/null \
     && perl genmakefile.pl \
     && mv Makefile ../gen/ \
    echo "" > gen/SvcGenLog
```

(dropped the current directory prefix; you were using relative path at some points anyway)
And than just make the rule depend on `gen/SvcGenLog`. It would be a bit more readable and you can make it depend on the `genscript/genmakefile.pl` too, so the `Makefile` in `gen` will be regenerated if you modify the script. Of course if anything else affects the content of the `Makefile`, you can make the rule depend on that too.

Answer (score 3):

Note that each line executed by a make file is run in its own shell anyway. If you change directory, it won't affect subsequent lines. So you probably have little use for pushd and popd, your problem is more the opposite, that of getting the directory to stay changed for as long as you need it!

Answer (score 2):

Run "apt install bash"
It will install everything you need and the command will work