# How to change shell of npm install

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to npm install a package in Ubuntu 16.04. I get the following error message:

```
npm install 

...

> padlock@2.0.0-beta.1 bower-install /home/kent/Documents/padlock
> pushd app && bower install && popd app

sh: 1: pushd: not found
```

## My Research

According to [/bin/sh: pushd: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5193048/2750819), my problem is clearly that npm install is trying to execute pushd with sh not bash.

However, my default shell is already bash

```
$ env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo $0
bash
```

and I'm not sure what I need to change. I've also tried adding SHELL=/bin/bash before I execute pushd app but I have had no luck with that either.

Comment: Try to use `ls -al /bin/bash` to see if `bash` is linked to other shell.

Comment: ls -al /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x ... /bin/bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

npm-scripts run using `sh`

> Scripts are run by passing the line as a script argument to sh

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#exiting

If you want to use bash for your scripts make the script

`bash -c 'pushd app && bower install && popd'`

Update: As of [November 2017](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/f13c5c0dc06a6db57ac368161510d8ff2fae6054) you can now set `script-shell` in `.npmrc` to use a custom shell

Comment: Interesting...how did the padlock developers think pushd would just work then?

Comment: `sh` is bash on some systems but on debian based systems it's dash

Comment: Interesting workaround, but not the answer to the question, "How to change shell of npm install?"

Comment: @MarkHu Well the answer is you can't without potentially ruining your operating system.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work around a similar situation by creating this file in my project directory:

```
$ cat .npmrc

script-shell=/bin/bash
```

FWIW, the issue I stumbled upon was relying on bash-specific "curly-brace expansion" commands in the `postinstall` section of the `package.json` file for the offending module. That malformed command works in MacOS, but not Linux.