# Youtrack installation and starting failes

Tags: jar, debian, youtrack

I wanted to install Youtrack on my Debian 9.3 system. Before installation the system was updated.

I used the instructions on the Jetbrains webpage: [Jetbrains Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-JAR-as-Service-Linux.html#linux-installation)
I started the script as described and get the following error when running `/etc/init.d/youtrack status`:

```
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Test Wrapper Sample Application...
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development youtrack[14205]: /etc/init.d/youtrack: 21: /etc/init.d/youtrack: pushd: not found
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development su[14261]: Successful su for youtrack by root
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development su[14261]: + ??? root:youtrack
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development su[14261]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user youtrack by (uid=0)
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development youtrack[14205]: /etc/init.d/youtrack: 21: /etc/init.d/youtrack: pushd: not found
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development youtrack[14205]: Starting youtrack...
Jan 30 15:13:18 eggplant-development youtrack[14205]: "/home/youtrack/standalone/bin/wrapper" "/home/youtrack/standalone/conf/wrapper.conf" wrapper.syslog.ident=youtrack wrapper.pidfile="/home/youtrack/standalone/youtrack.pid" wrapper.da
Jan 30 15:13:19 eggplant-development youtrack[14205]: /etc/init.d/youtrack: 557: /etc/init.d/youtrack: popd: not found
Jan 30 15:13:19 eggplant-development systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Test Wrapper Sample Application.
```

All files and versions are like in the installation instructions specified.

Does anyone knows that issue or has an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not able to find the "pushd" command which is a bash builtin. My guess is that your /bin/sh points to a shell that does not come with a pushd. You could force it to run in bash by adding

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

at the beginning of `/etc/init.d/youtrack`.

It might also help to check out [/bin/sh: pushd: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193048/bin-sh-pushd-not-found) which discusses this error in a bit more detail.