# How to convert relative path to absolute path in Unix

Tags: unix

I want to convert

Relative Path - `/home/stevin/data/APP_SERVICE/../datafile.txt`

to

Absolute Path - `/home/stevin/data/datafile.txt`

Is there a built-in tool in Unix to do this or any good ideas as to how can I implement this?

Comment: Maybe you can update your question to indicate why do you think you need to do this. This is a feature! Good luck.

Comment: I am stamping Relative Path into a small file and using this entry to copy file to a different location later on. However, APP_SERVICE folder may sometimes not exists and causing copying using this relative path to fail.

Answer (score 34):

`readlink -f /home/stevin/data/APP_SERVICE/../datafile.txt` should do what you're looking for, assuming your Unix/Linux has `readlink`.

Answer (score 23):

Something like this can help for directories: (For files, append with `basename`)

```
echo $(cd ../dir1/dir2/; pwd)
```

For files,

```
filepath=../dir1/dir2/file3
echo $(cd $(dirname $filepath); pwd)/$(basename $filepath)
```

Comment: +1 Actually `echo "$(cd $(dirname $thingie); pwd)/$(basename $thingie)"` does the trick for both files _and_ directories, since `dirname` and `basename` merely process strings and don't care whether the string they work on is an actual FS object

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Ohh, yes, that was actually a typo, that I didn't see till now, to have both `../dir1/dir2/file3` and `$t` both at once. I will fix that. :)

Comment: Since OP mentioned not even having `readlink`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20198034/321973)'s a solution that doesn't even require `dirname` and `basename`...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler `thingie=/;echo "$(cd $(dirname $thingie); pwd)/$(basename $thingie)"` outputs `///`. Not good

Comment: @beluchin You might want to put that comment below the linked answer instead of this one - and additional slashes are actually permitted and mostly ignored, AFAIK

Comment: Warning that if you have `CDPATH` set, `cd` will echo new paths, so you need to kill its output: `echo $(cd $(dirname $filepath) > /dev/null; pwd)/$(basename $filepath)`

Comment: This is my favorite solution, as it does not rely on any packages being installed, should work in nearly any shell, and is compact and easy to read.

Answer (score 23):

I'm surprised nobody mentions `realpath` yet. Pass your paths to `realpath` and it will canonicalize them.

```
$ ls
Changes
dist.ini

$ ls | xargs realpath
/home/steven/repos/perl-Alt-Module-Path-SHARYANTO/Changes
/home/steven/repos/perl-Alt-Module-Path-SHARYANTO/dist.ini
```

Comment: Is `realpath` installed by default on your system?

Comment: It isn't clear what "built-in tool in Unix" means (OP might mean internal shell command). Even "installed by default" is vague because OS installers usually allow the user to choose which components to install. As for `realpath`, it comes with Debian/Ubuntu and is just an apt-get/aptitude away. But anyway, OP also asks about "any good ideas".

Comment: On my system, I need to add the `-f` option.

Comment: Nice! Also, the man page of readlink says "Note realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality."

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Thrustmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246338/321973) but with pure bash:

```
THING="/home/stevin/data/APP_SERVICE/../datafile.txt"
echo "$(cd ${THING%/*}; pwd)/${THING##*/}"
```

Of course the `cd` requires the path to actually exist, which may not always be the case - in that case, you'll probably have a simpler life by writing a small Python script instead...

Answer (score 0):

This is my helper function

```sh
# get a real path from a relative path.
function realPath() {
  if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    currentPath="$(pwd)" # save current path
    cd "$1" || exit 1 # cd to the checking dir
    pwd
    cd "$currentPath" || exit 1 # restore to original path
  else
    echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")" && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"
  fi
}
```