# Is there a simple way to copy a file to clipboard in Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, clipboard

I work primarily in terminal but I do communicate with others in GUI apps, e.g. Slack. Sometimes I got some logs / events and I piped them into a file, I can copy the file content to clipboard easily but I can not find a way to copy the file itself, any idea?

I've tried pbcopy, cat and piping around, no luck.

Comment: Unclear what is meant by "the file itself".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do (essentially, the equivalent of selecting a file in Finder and choosing Edit menu > Copy), this should work:

```
osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'set the clipboard to item 1 of argv as «class furl»' -e 'end run' /path/to/file
```

Note that I don't think this'll work with relative paths or bare filenames. If you want to make this into a script or function, you should probably add a step to convert relative paths to asolute... which is tricky on macOS since it doesn't have `realpath` and its `readlink` doesn't have the `-f` option. See ["How to retrieve absolute path given relative"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175264/how-to-retrieve-absolute-path-given-relative) and the linked duplicate questions.

Also, for completeness, if you just want to copy the contents of a file as text, it's much easier: `pbcopy </path/to/file`