# Expand a possible relative path in bash

Tags: linux, bash, absolute-path

As arguments to my script there are some file paths.  Those can, of course, be relative (or contain ~). But for the functions I've written I need paths that are absolute, but do not have their symlinks resolved.

Is there any function for this?

Comment: Try the readlink function - http://andy.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/bash-equivalent-for-php-realpath/

Comment: `readlink` resolves symlinks; the OP doesn't want that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting relative path into absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045253/converting-relative-path-into-absolute-path)

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file)

Comment: `echo $(cd some_directory && pwd)`, do not resolve symlink, fails if some_directory not exist. working directory not affected. or assign to a variable `MY_PATH=$(cd some_directory && pwd)`.

Comment: Or just `realpath -s "./some/dir"` as per recommendation from readlink docs. Quick, easy, and no functions (if your OS supports it, which it should?) like my answer states. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64706902/2024228

Answer (score 88):

`MY_PATH=$(readlink -f $YOUR_ARG)` will resolve relative paths like `"./"` and `"../"`

Consider this as well ([source](http://andy.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/bash-equivalent-for-php-realpath/)):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_resolve()
{
cd "$1" 2>/dev/null || return $?  # cd to desired directory; if fail, quell any error messages but return exit status
echo "`pwd -P`" # output full, link-resolved path
}

# sample usage
if abs_path="`dir_resolve \"$1\"`"
then
echo "$1 resolves to $abs_path"
echo pwd: `pwd` # function forks subshell, so working directory outside function is not affected
else
echo "Could not reach $1"
fi
```

Comment: that certainly nice, but the problem is that simlinks are resolved, and that would lead to some confusion with the users.

Comment: `man pwd`: "-P Display the physical current working directory (all symbolic links resolved)", just remove the `-P`

Comment: To get the `readlink -f` functionality on OS X, you can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then run: `$ brew install coreutils`  You can then use `greadlink -f` .

Answer (score 52):

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-return-full-path-and-filename-680368/page3.html has the following

```
function abspath {
    if [[ -d "$1" ]]
    then
        pushd "$1" >/dev/null
        pwd
        popd >/dev/null
    elif [[ -e "$1" ]]
    then
        pushd "$(dirname "$1")" >/dev/null
        echo "$(pwd)/$(basename "$1")"
        popd >/dev/null
    else
        echo "$1" does not exist! >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

which uses `pushd`/`popd` to get into a state where `pwd` is useful.

Comment: Sadly, this is really the best answer on here and it's not voted up to where it belongs.  +1 for accurately answering the OP's question.  He wants symlinks not resolved, which is really a question of bash's local `DIRSTACK` and nothing else.  Nice solution!

Comment: When aiming for standard `sh` compatibility, `pushd; cd <dir>; <cmd>; popd` can be replaced with `(cd <dir>; <cmd>)`.

Answer (score 20):

If your OS supports it, use:

```
realpath -s "./some/dir"
```

And using it in a variable:

```
some_path="$(realpath -s "./some/dir")"
```

Which will expand your path. Tested on Ubuntu and CentOS, might not be available on yours. Some recommend readlink, but documentation for readlink says:

> Note realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality.

In case people wonder why I quote my variables, it's to preserve spaces in paths. Like doing `realpath some path` will give you two different path results. But `realpath "some path"` will return one. Quoted parameters ftw :)

Thanks to NyanPasu64 for the heads up. You'll want to add `-s` if you don't want it to follow the symlinks.

Comment: The best answer, by far. All the rest either ignore the requirement of not following symlinks, or are way too complicated.

Comment: On Linux, realpath follows symlinks, which OP specifically requested to not happen.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @nyanpasu64 , I edited the answer to include not following symlinks.

Answer (score 18):

Simple one-liner:

```
function abs_path {
  (cd "$(dirname '$1')" &>/dev/null && printf "%s/%s" "$PWD" "${1##*/}")
}
```

Usage:

```
function do_something {
    local file=$(abs_path $1)
    printf "Absolute path to %s: %s\n" "$1" "$file"
}
do_something $HOME/path/to/some\ where
```

I am still trying to figure out how I can get it to be completely oblivious to whether the path exists or not (so it can be used when creating files as well).

Comment: Won't this change the current working directory? Should I `cd -` afterward to reset it?

Comment: No need. Note the parens, they cause the commands inside to be run in a subshell. The state (e.g. the working directory) of a subshell does not leak to its parent shell. Read more here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: Nice one-liner. There's an issue, though: if the expanded value of $1 does not have any slash (i.e. it is a file name in the current directory), then ${1%/*} expands to the filename itself and the cd command fails. You may want to use $(dirname $1) instead, which will expand to '.' in that case.

Comment: You're right, updated. I have some quoting problems with replacing `${1##*/}` with `basename` though, without putting it in a separate variable, paths with spaces don't work properly.

Comment: Why `"$(pwd)"` instead of `"$PWD"`, saving a subshell-invocation? (Not criticising; genuinely asking. Are there issues with `$PWD`?)

Comment: Huh, never thought of that. There's no reason to not use `$PWD`, it works just as well - fixing it now. Thanks :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for directories: `abs_path /tmp/tmp.EcSXKZ9Dsm/source` is giving me `/tmp/tmp.EcSXKZ9Dsm/source/source`

Comment: Make sure the path exists. As said, I haven't been able to make a nice one-line that works without the paths having to exist.

Comment: This mostly seems to work, except that with a path like `/some/filesystem/location/MyApp.app/MyApp` (specified in the command-line as `./MyApp.app/MyApp`) the `abs_path` function returns `/some/filesystem/location/MyApp`.

Comment: I had to use `"$1"` instead of `'$1'` to make it work.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to exist for valid directories when specified with a trailing `/`. Works well if removed, but for robustness I ended up using @MikeSamuel answer.

Comment: @BryanP I actually ended up going completely overboard for the dotfile synchronizer that I'm maintaining. It has a clean_path() function that removes unneeded path parts, if you stick a relative path at the end of `$PWD` and run it through that, it should work quite well: https://github.com/andsens/homeshick/blob/490013f818e26fa477141846614ea873d5ef645f/lib/fs.sh#L66-L152

Comment: @andsens: Wow, looks nice and comprehensive. Might be worth posting as another answer or possibly as a greatly expanded edit to this one.

Comment: If you don't want to use functions and want a quick easy way, you can use `realpath -s "./some/dir"` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64706902/2024228

Answer (score 9):

This does the trick for me on OS X: `$(cd SOME_DIRECTORY 2> /dev/null && pwd -P)`

It should work anywhere. The other solutions seemed too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `readlink -f <relative-path>`, e.g.

```
export FULLPATH=`readlink -f ./`
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is more readable and does not use a subshell and does not change the current dir:

```
dir_resolve() {
  local dir=`dirname "$1"`
  local file=`basename "$1"`
  pushd "$dir" &>/dev/null || return $? # On error, return error code
  echo "`pwd -P`/$file" # output full, link-resolved path with filename
  popd &> /dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

on OS X you can use

```
stat -f "%N" YOUR_PATH
```

on linux you might have `realpath` executable. if not, the following might work (not only for links):

```
readlink -c YOUR_PATH
```

Comment: The OS X answer does not work. `stat -f "%N" PATH` gives me exactly the same path I gave it.

Answer (score 2):

There's another method. You can use python embedding in bash script to resolve a relative path.

```
abs_path=$(python3 - <<END
from pathlib import Path
path = str(Path("$1").expanduser().resolve())
print(path)
END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

self edit, I just noticed the OP said he's not looking for symlinks resolved:

"But for the functions I've written I need paths that are absolute, but do not have their symlinks resolved."

So guess this isn't so apropos to his question after all. :)

Since I've run into this many times over the years, and this time around I needed a pure bash portable version that I could use on OSX and linux, I went ahead and wrote one:

The living version lives here:

https://github.com/keen99/shell-functions/tree/master/resolve_path

but for the sake of SO, here's the current version (I feel it's well tested..but I'm open to feedback!)

Might not be difficult to make it work for plain bourne shell (sh), but I didn't try...I like $FUNCNAME too much. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

resolve_path() {
    #I'm bash only, please!
    # usage:  resolve_path <a file or directory> 
    # follows symlinks and relative paths, returns a full real path
    #
    local owd="$PWD"
    #echo "$FUNCNAME for $1" >&2
    local opath="$1"
    local npath=""
    local obase=$(basename "$opath")
    local odir=$(dirname "$opath")
    if [[ -L "$opath" ]]
    then
    #it's a link.
    #file or directory, we want to cd into it's dir
        cd $odir
    #then extract where the link points.
        npath=$(readlink "$obase")
        #have to -L BEFORE we -f, because -f includes -L :(
        if [[ -L $npath ]]
         then
        #the link points to another symlink, so go follow that.
            resolve_path "$npath"
            #and finish out early, we're done.
            return $?
            #done
        elif [[ -f $npath ]]
        #the link points to a file.
         then
            #get the dir for the new file
            nbase=$(basename $npath)
            npath=$(dirname $npath)
            cd "$npath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        elif [[ -d $npath ]]
         then
        #the link points to a directory.
            cd "$npath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        else
            echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: unknown condition inside link!!" >&2
            echo "opath [[ $opath ]]" >&2
            echo "npath [[ $npath ]]" >&2
            return 1
        fi
    else
        if ! [[ -e "$opath" ]]
         then
            echo "$FUNCNAME: $opath: No such file or directory" >&2
            return 1
            #and break early
        elif [[ -d "$opath" ]]
         then 
            cd "$opath"
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            retval=0
            #done
        elif [[ -f "$opath" ]]
         then
            cd $odir
            ndir=$(pwd -P)
            nbase=$(basename "$opath")
            retval=0
            #done
        else
            echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: unknown condition outside link!!" >&2
            echo "opath [[ $opath ]]" >&2
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    #now assemble our output
    echo -n "$ndir"
    if [[ "x${nbase:=}" != "x" ]]
     then
        echo "/$nbase"
    else 
        echo
    fi
    #now return to where we were
    cd "$owd"
    return $retval
}
```

here's a classic example, thanks to brew:

```
%% ls -l `which mvn`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 draistrick  502  29 Dec 17 10:50 /usr/local/bin/mvn@ -> ../Cellar/maven/3.2.3/bin/mvn
```

use this function and it will return the -real- path:

```
%% cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
. resolve_path.inc
echo
echo "relative symlinked path:"
which mvn
echo
echo "and the real path:"
resolve_path `which mvn`


%% test.sh

relative symlinked path:
/usr/local/bin/mvn

and the real path:
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec/bin/mvn
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use bash exclusively? I needed to do this and got fed up with differences between Linux and OS X. So I used PHP for a quick and dirty solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/php <-- or wherever
<?php
{
   if($argc!=2)
      exit();
   $fname=$argv[1];
   if(!file_exists($fname))
      exit();
   echo realpath($fname)."\n";
}
?>
```

I know it's not a very elegant solution but it does work.

Comment: This does nothing but return the path to the file if you already know the path to the file or the file is in the current dir...does not find the file in the PATH settings