# Whats the command to quickly get the fulllpath of a given file?

Tags: linux, shell, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file)

Say I'm in a directory `/usr/temp/foo`, which has a file named `bar.txt`

How do I get the fullpath of `bar.txt`? (which should be `/usr/tem/foo/bar.txt`)

Comment: euh, `echo /usr/temp/foo/bar.txt`...?

Comment: No, but if I have 1000 files, I wouldn't want to do `echo pwd ...` for all 1000 of those

Comment: Then save $(pwd) in a variable, and prepend the variable.

Comment: `bash` already has a variable `$PWD` that stores the current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
readlink -f bar.txt
```

Extra text to make SO happy.

Comment: Perhaps, but `realpath` isn't by default on my mint machine.  I figured `readlink` as part of the GNU tools, would be more common.

Comment: How about printing fullpaths of all files ending with certain extension? I've tried `readline -f *.c` (all C-source files), but it didn't seem to work?

Comment: Combine it with find:  `find . -name '*.c' -exec readlink -f {} \;`