# Delete non git directory in git bash, windows

Tags: command-line, git-bash

```
xx@xx-PC ~/xampp/htdocs/sites
$ rmdir /s "yo-2"
rmdir: `/s': No such file or directory
rmdir: `yo-2': Directory not empty

xx@xx-PC ~/xampp/htdocs/sites
$ rmdir "yo-2"
rmdir: `yo-2': Directory not empty
```

I cant seem to get rmdir to work in git bash. Its not in a git repo and I've tried the above. Mkdir works as expected, why doesnt this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`rmdir` will not work if directory is empty

Try

```
  rm -rf yo-2
```

`git-bash` is a Linux like shell

Comment: This works except for the node components folder - saying 'directory not empty' OR 'file / path too long'. Any ideas how to get round this?

Comment: rm could fail when doing `rm dir/*` and node contains a lot of files, and substitution fails, or when there is a really long path, or maybe dealing with path names that contains strange chars, or when there are open files into the path. Any clue?

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to remove an entire directory regardless of contents, you could use:

```
rm <dirname> -rf
```

Comment: This works as the marked answer does but is much slower. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: it is the same command how did it run slower? thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

just use the command below:

rm -rfv *mydirectory*

Answer (score 0):

After trying  out a couple of other commands, this worked for me:

```
rm dirname -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I believe it still can help someone with performance problems on Windows systems. It is **REALLY FAST to delete** on Windows using git bash comparing with just the ordinary `rm -rf`.  The trick here is to move the file/directory to another random name in a temporary directory at the same drive (on Windows) or at the same partition (on *nix systems) and invoke the `rm -rf` command in background mode. At least you don't need to wait for a blocking IO task and OS will perform the deletion as soon it gets idle.

Depending on the system you are using you may need to install the `realpath` program (ie macOS). Another alternative is to write a bash portable function like in this post: [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file).

```sh
fast_rm() {
    path=$(realpath $1) # getting the absolute path
    echo $path
    if [ -e $path ]; then
        export TMPDIR="$(dirname $(mktemp -u))"
        kernel=$(uname | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
        # if windows, make sure to use the same drive
        if [[ "${kernel}" == "mingw"* ]]; then # git bash
            export TMPDIR=$(echo "${path}" | awk '{ print substr($0, 1, 2)"/temp"}')
            if [ ! -e $TMPDIR ]; then mkdir -p $TMPDIR; fi
        fi
        if [ "${kernel}" == "darwin" ]; then MD5=md5; else MD5=md5sum; fi
        rnd=$(echo $RANDOM | $MD5 | awk '{print $0}')
        to_remove="${TMPDIR}/$(basename ${path})-${rnd}"
        mv "${path}" "${to_remove}"
        nohup rm -rf "${to_remove}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    fi
}

# invoking the function
directory_or_file=./vo-2
fast_delete $directory_or_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. this is worked for me

rimraf is a Node.js package, which is the UNIX command `rm -rf` for node, so you will need to install Node.js which includes npm. Then you can run:

> npm install -g rimraf

Then you can run rimraf from the command line.

> rimraf directoryname

visit https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete

I found this solution because npm itself was causing this problem due to the way it nests dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Late reply, but for those who search a solution, for me the

```
rm <dirname> -rf
```

wasn't good, I always get the directory non-empty or path too long on node directories.

A really simple solution : 
Move the directory you want to delete to the root of your disk (to shorten your path) and then you can delete it normally.

Comment: This is a problem if you have too long a pathname, but it shouldn't be relevant to the question here.