# Unable to run React project - seeking guidance and solutions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

I am currently encountering an unexpected error while trying to run my React JS project. I have shared the GitHub URL for my project here: https://github.com/huzaifa-aslam/ozone

I have installed the development dependencies using npm i, but I ran into a node-sass error. I managed to resolve the node-sass error, but I am now stuck with the following error message: "npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok".

I would be grateful if anyone could offer their guidance and assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try [`npm cache clean --force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613486/12737879), then try removing node_modules and package-lock.json (for windows you can run [`rm -rf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22324987/12737879) to make the deletion faster) and re-run `npm i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot run any project because of gyp error. How can I fix this: npm ERR! gyp verb cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599040/i-cannot-run-any-project-because-of-gyp-error-how-can-i-fix-this-npm-err-gyp)