# List files from directory recursively with directory name

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I am having the following directory structures:

```
~/mydir/dir1/f1.jpg
~/mydir/dir1/f2.jpg

~/mydir/dir2/f3.jpg
~/mydir/dir2/f4.jpg
~/mydir/dir2/f5.jpg
~/mydir/dir2/f6.jpg

~/mydir/dir3/f7.jpg
```

i.e. directory (`mydir`) is having many subdirectories which in turn have many images in them. `dir1`, `dir2` etc does not have any more subdirectories.

I am looking for a script (any language, shell, python etc) which can produce the output like:

```
<absolute path of f1.jpg> dir1
<absolute path of f2.jpg> dir1
<absolute path of f3.jpg> dir2
.
.
<absolute path of f6.jpg> dir2
<absolute path of f7.jpg> dir3
```

i.e. full absolute path of all the files in all the directories in mydir, followed by a space and then that file's directory (i.e. which last directory that file is in).

I am using `find . -name \* -print` to get the recursive file list but I am not sure how to get the exact output as desired.

My directory structure:
[image]

Comment: See: [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3915040/3776858)

Comment: You could use readlink -f ~/mydir/dirX/* where X is the number of your directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python

```
import os
for root, _, fnames in os.walk('/mydir'):
    for fname in fnames:
       print os.path.join(root, fname), fname
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ls -d1 path/*/*` for absolute path, then pipe it to Perl for printing in the particular format

```perl
ls -d1 ~/mydir/*/* | perl -lne 'print "<$_> ", m|.*/(.*)/[^/]*|'
```

The `~/` does get expanded to the absolute path. **Output exactly as requested**

```
</path_mydir/last_dir/filename> last_dir
...
```

---

If recursive listing is needed use `path/**` with shells that support it (most).

Answer (score 0):

if you have find

```
find . -type f -printf "%f %h\n"
```

with the embellishments

```
find . -type f -printf "<absolute path of %f> %h\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd ~
$ find mydir -type f | perl -p -e 's|(.*)/([^/]+)\n$|\1/\2 \1\n|g'
mydir/dir1/f1.jpg mydir/dir1
mydir/dir1/f2.jpg mydir/dir1
mydir/dir2/f3.jpg mydir/dir2
mydir/dir2/f4.jpg mydir/dir2
mydir/dir2/f5.jpg mydir/dir2
mydir/dir2/f6.jpg mydir/dir2
mydir/dir3/f7.jpg mydir/dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **find `pwd`** instead **find .** or **find relatif_dir** to take absolute path :

```
cd ~/mydir ; find `pwd`  -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'echo "<absolute path of "`basename {}`">" `dirname {}`' \;
```

or

```
 cd ~/mydir ; find `pwd`  -type f -name "*.jpg"  | sed -e "s/\(.*\)\/\([^\/]*\)/<absolute path of \2> \1/g"
```