# Executable shell script for jar

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have jar, which must get 2 parameters from command line,
I create the sh script (test.sh):

```
java -jar target/test-SNAPSHOT.jar $1 $2
```

If I make the script global, how can I pass the full path to the files in the parameters to the parameters of the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, then you are interested in the absolute paths to your script parameters. So you could use `realpath`.

Script call:

```
test.sh $(realpath para1) $(realpath para2)
```

Or in your script:

```
java -jar target/test-SNAPSHOT.jar "$(realpath "$1")" "$(realpath "$2")"
```

Some more alternatives are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file).