# Source bash script to another one

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)

I have bash script `test.sh` which use functions from another `search.sh` script by following lines:

```
source ../scripts/search.sh
<call some functions from search.sh>
```

Both scripts are located in git repository. `search.sh` in `<git_root>/scripts/` directory, `test.sh` is located in the same directory (but, generally speaking, could be located anywhere inside `<git_root>` directory - I mean I can't rely on the following `source search.sh` approach ).

When I call `test.sh` script from `<git_root>/scripts/` everything works well, but as soon as I change current working directory `test.sh` fails:

```
cd <git_root>/scripts/
./test.sh         //OK
cd ..
./scripts/test.sh //FAILS
./scripts/test.sh: line 1: ../scripts/search.sh: No file or directory ...
```

Thus what I have:

1. Relative path of `search.sh` script towards `<git_root>` directory

**What I want:** To have ability to run `test.sh` from anywhere inside `<git_root>` without errors.

**P.S.:** It is not possible to use permanent absolute path to `search.sh` as git repository can be cloned to any location.

Comment: It is not duplicate. I tried methods from this link. But it's not my case as here I do not need to get path of my `test.sh` script.

Comment: Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but if you currently `source` a relative path from the current directory, sourcing a relative path from the script's path seems like a good improvement. The only complication is if the user moves the script to a different location altogether, but I cannot imagine how you would fix that, other than with an environment variable.

Comment: If the `search.sh` script is in the same directory as `test.sh`, then finding the path that `test.sh` is in will most definitely help, as then you use that path to find your other script.

Answer (score 3):

If both the scripts are in the same directory, then if you get the directory that the running script is in, you use that as the directory to call the other script:

```
# Get the directory this script is in
pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
SCRIPTPATH=`pwd -P`
popd > /dev/null

# Now use that directory to call the other script
source $SCRIPTPATH/search.sh
```

Taken from the accepted answer of the question I marked this question a duplicatre of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774063/440558

Comment: Seems a lot easier to do `SCRIPTPATH=$( readlink -f $0 )`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
# Get path the Git repo
GIT_ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

# Load the search functions
source $GIT_ROOT/scripts/search.sh
```

[How get Git root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)!

Or like [@Joachim Pileborg says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14237355/1390306), but you have to pay attention that you must know the path of this one to another script;

```
# Call the other script
source $SCRIPTPATH/../scripts/search.sh
```

```
# Or if it is in another path
source $SCRIPTPATH/../scripts/seachers/search.sh
```

The Apache Tomcat scripts use this approach:

```
# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`
```

Any way, you have to put this snippet on all scripts that use other scripts.

Comment: Does any other way, without using git features as in reliable code I must use check of existence of `git` command. I mean in every new script I must use some duplicated code: check `git` existence, getting `GIT_ROOT`, etc...

Comment: What if the user isn't in the Git repository itself? Is there a way to find a Git local repository?

Comment: @DavidW. the most reliable way of finding a Git local repository is to move upwards in the directory structure until you find a `.git` directory or hit some defined directory, e.g., `$HOME`, `/`, etc.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I took it from the OP that the directory he is using may be outside of the Git repository itself. For example, he's in `$HOME/bin`, but the Git repo is in `$HOME/work/git_repo`.

Comment: From OP: `Both scripts are located in git repository.` ... `What I want: To have ability to run test.sh from anywhere inside <git_root> without errors.`

Comment: @user966467, If you clone your Git repo you have git command, simple that!

Comment: @user966467, you can do as the Scripts Apache Tomcat (startup.sh, catalina.sh, ...) -> [snippet](http://pastie.org/private/avdgijufbaoakvkhxcwt5w)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to identify this Git repository location? An environment variable set? You could set `PATH` in the script itself to include the Git repository:

```
 PATH="$GIT_REPO_LOCATION/scripts:$PATH"
 . search.sh
```

Once the script is complete, your `PATH` will revert to its old value, and `$GIT_REPO_LOCATION/scripts` will no longer be part of the `PATH`.

The question is finding this location to begin with. I guess you could do something like this in your script:

```
GIT_LOCATION=$(find $HOME -name "search.sh" | head -1)
GIT_SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname $GIT_LOCATION)
PATH="$GIT_SCRIPT_DIR:$PATH"
. search.sh
```

By the way, now that `$PATH` is set, I can call the script via `search.sh` and not `./search.sh` which you had to do when you were in the scripts directory, and your `PATH` didn't include `.` which is the current directory (and PATH shouldn't include `.` because it is a security hole).

One more note, you could search for the `.git` directory too which might be the Git repository you're looking for:

```
GIT_LOCATION=$(find $HOME -name ".git" -type d | head -1)
PATH="$GIT_LOCATION:$PATH"
. search.sh
```

Comment: But how to avoid problems with similar git repositories. There is no guarantee that someone did `git clone <link> first-git-repo` and then `git clone <link> second-git-repo`. Also in general case this solution can take too much time for searching this git repository. Also in general case we should use not only `$HOME` dir, but `/ (root)` dir.

Comment: For these reasons I simplified the task. And even for this one can't find reliable approach ;)

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the second line of the second code block.

Comment: @user966467 Okay, how do **you** know where that Git repository is located? However you find the location of that Git repository, you'll have to let your program know.

Comment: I suggest that I can use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14237207/source-bash-script-to-another-one/14238266#comment19753159-14237207 which was mentioned by @Joachim Pileborg.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who would rather not use git's features for finding the parent directory. If you can be sure you'll always be running the script from within the git directory, you can use something like this:

```
git_root=""
while /bin/true ; do
    if [[ "$(pwd)" == "$HOME" ]] || [[ "$(pwd)" == "/" ]] ; then
        break
    fi

    if [[ -d ".git" ]] ; then
        git_root="$(pwd)"
        break
    fi

    cd ..
done
```

I haven't tested this but it will just loop back until it hits your home directory or / and it will see if there is a `.git` directory in each parent directory. If there is, it sets the `git_root` variable and it will break out. If it doesn't find one, `git_root` will just be an empty string. Then you can do:

```
if [[ -n "$git_root" ]] ; then
    . ${git_root}/scripts/search.sh
fi
```

IHTH