# Binary file in npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, binary, npm

I try to create an npm package, which can be started as a command from shell. I have `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "",
    "watch": "",
    "node-promise": "",
    "rmdir": "",
    "should": "",
    "websocket": ""
  },
  "bin": "myapp"
}
```

and `myapp`

```
#!/bin/bash

path=`dirname "$0"`
file="/myapp.js"

node $path$file $1 &
```

But I get an error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin/myapp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

The problem is that myapp.js is in another directory. How can I get this directory name from my script? Or maybe there is better way to do this?

Comment: Why dont you give that myapp.js `directory path` on cmdline call the script as `./scriptname.sh 'directory_path'`and then instead of `node $path$file $1 &` use `node $1/${file}`, if you do this you wont need `path=\`dirname "$0"\` `

Comment: Because this file is part of a package. And I want this script to be a simple, global command.

Comment: You'll need to resolve the `$0` symlink path into the actual file path. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself ?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know where the `myapp.js` is, it is installed with a package and should be in different directories. The question is how can I find path to this file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, you can put your `myapp.js` file into `bin`.
So, the bin key in package.json file should be like this :

```
"bin": { "myapp" : "<relative_path_to_myapp.js>/lib/myapp.js" }
```

At the first line in `myapp.js`, you must add this shebang line :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

It tells the system to use `node` to run `myapp.js`.

---

... Or if you don't want to call `myapp.js` directly, you can create a script like this to be your executable file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var myapp = require('<relative_path_to_myapp.js>/myapp.js');
myapp.doSth();
```

and in package.json :

```
"bin" : { "myapp" : "<relative_path_to_the_script>/script.js" }
```

By doing this either way, you can avoid finding the path to your nodemodule.

---

But... if you insist to use your old `myapp` bash script, then you can find the path to the module with this :

```
myapp_path=$( npm explore -g myapp -- "pwd" )
```

Hope these help :D

Answer (score 3):

**https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin**

From the above link:

> To use this, supply a **bin** field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into **prefix/bin** for global installs, or **./node_modules/.bin/** for local installs.
>
> For example, myapp could have this:
>
> ```json
> { "bin" : { "myapp" : "./cli.js" } }
> ```
>
> So, when you install myapp, it’ll create a symlink from the **cli.js** script to **/usr/local/bin/myapp**.