# Weird behaviour of $BASH_SOURCE

Tags: bash, function, global

If you have foo.sh that declares a global function:

```
myfunction(){ echo $*;}
declare -fx myfunction
```

And you source it:

```
. foo.sh
```

And then you call the global function from bar.sh:

```
myfunction $BASH_SOURCE
myfunction a b c
myfunction $BASH_SOURCE
```

The third call produces a blank line, unless bar.sh is being sourced. Any ideas how to bypass this problem?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `/bin/bar.sh
a b c
/bin/bar.sh`

$BASH_SOURCE returns an empty value if it is not being invoked by the function for the first time, unles the script is being sourced

Comment: Might be related to a Bash bug discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953325/2866527).

Answer (score 0):

Weird, this definitely looks like a bug. Possibly related to bash's shell function importing mechanism (when a shell function is found serialized in the environment and deserialized into the new process).

I just found that if you source `foo.sh` from inside `bar.sh` then the bug disappears:

```
. foo.sh
myfunction ${BASH_SOURCE[@]}
myfunction a b c
myfunction ${BASH_SOURCE[@]}
```

results in output

```
> ./bar.sh
./bar.sh
a b c
./bar.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the bash manual, `BASH_SOURCE` is an array, each element of which is the filename associated with the corresponding element of `FUNCNAME`, which "exists  only when a shell function is executing".

So any value in `BASH_SOURCE` outside of a function call (and the evaluation of function arguments are outside of a function call) is an undocumented use; the variable has no documented value at that point.

Comment: So tell me, how do you then use functions in all of your scripts? Currently, I have around 25 one-liner scripts that I am sourcing from all the other scripts, any better solution?

Comment: @Ulrik: I'm not sure that I understand the question (although my answer is that I keep a single file of functions, which is effectively my bash library, as well as project-specific files of functions.) When you execute `myfunction "$BASH_SOURCE"`, the variable is being expanded in the context of the shell, not of the function, because arguments are evaluated before functions are called, just like in almost every other language. If you inspected `$BASH_SOURCE` during the execution of `myfunction`, it would probably have the expected value.

Comment: @Ulrik: Moreover, `$FUNCNAME` has no value at the point at which you inspect `$BASH_SOURCE`, and my reading of the bash manual is that you only look at items in `$BASH_SOURCE` which correspond to entries in `$FUNCNAME`. Perhaps your expectations are different; certainly the fact that `$BASH_SOURCE` has a value when the documentation implies that it shouldn't is a bit unexpected. If all that wasn't clear from my answer, let me know and I will edit it.