# Bash script to get its full path (use 'source' to invoke it)

Tags: bash

In a bash script, is there any method to get the full path of itself?

```
$ source ~/dev/setup.sh
```

I have tried $_, $-, $0..., but all are irrelevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)

Answer (score 2):

## The `$_` variable for location of a sourced script.

If you're sourcing the script, you can access the script name with `$_` (since `$0` will be the bash interpreter)

### Pure `bash` solution.

```
relname="$_";

# if script is in current directory, add ./
if [[ ! "$relname" =~ "/" ]]; then 
   relname="./$relname"; fi

relpath=`dirname $relname`;
name="${relname##*/}"

# convert to absolute path by cd-ing and using pwd.
cd "$relpath" >/dev/null;
path=`pwd`;
cd - >/dev/null;

# construct full path from absolute path and filename
fullpath="$path/$name";
```

Note that this script has the side effect of replacing the $OLDPWD (used by `cd -`) by the script directory. If you need to avoid this, just save $OLDPWD before the `cd -` and restore it at the end.

### Using `realpath`.

Assuming you have the `realpath` command installed, you can replace this code by the simple:

```
fullpath=`realpath "$_"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BASH_SOURCE` variable and then use `readlink` to get full path:

```
echo $BASH_SOURCE

# to get full path
fullpath=$(readlink --canonicalize --no-newline $BASH_SOURCE)
echo "$fullpath"
```

This will print the invoke path of the file being sourced, so in your case:

```
~/dev/setup.sh
~/dev/setup.sh
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)

> `BASH_SOURCE`
>
> An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the corresponding shell function names in the `FUNCNAME` array variable are defined. The shell function `${FUNCNAME[$i]}` is defined in the file `${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}` and called from `${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}`

Comment: This doesn't provide the full path. It provides whatever relative path you run the script from.

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer that **This will print the invoke path of the file being sourced**

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've also added a suggestion of calling `readlink` in case this file is being sourced with relative path.

Comment: @anubhava None of that was there when i commented.

Comment: You can check the edit history and see that `invoke path` line was always there esp since OP was invoking it as a full path script. However I added `readlink` to make it work in case relative path is being used also.

Comment: You can edit with 5 minutes and it doesn't show up in the edit history.

Comment: You may be aware that 5 min limit doesn't apply if a single comment appears and then it shows up in edit history

Answer (score 0):

Use [`realpath`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath).

```
$ realpath ~/dev/setup.sh
```

In a script:

```
rp=$(realpath "$0")
echo $rp
```

Comment: Note that one might want to give `realpath` some options, depending on how one would want it to deal with symlinks.