# custom icon in dialog

Tags: shell, applescript, osascript

I have a file in my current directory `Icon.png`.

How do I make this the icon for an applescript dialog?

I have tried

```
$ osascript -e 'display dialog "Hey" with icon file "./Icon.png"'
0:54: execution error: File file ./Icon.png wasn’t found. (-43)
```

So how can I get a local image and use it as the icon in a dialog?

I am happy to convert the image to a `.icns` if necessary.

Comment: osascript does not understand `./` you have to pass the full (HFS! - colon separated) path.

Comment: @vadian how do I get the full path? Pretend I have no idea what directory the script is running in. (The final thing has to be portable.)

Comment: I have no idea to do this in bash, on the AppleScript side you get the path to the current script with `path to me`

Comment: @vadian how does that get "injected" into the script?

Comment: You need to [retrieve the path in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself), then pass `POSIX file thePath as alias` where `thePath` is the slash separated full path to the icon

Comment: @vadian you just told me that in applescript I can use `path to me`....

Comment: @vadian how do i use `path to me` to get the path of an image file within this directory?

Comment: Once again, `path to me` works in a compiled (saved) AppleScript: `tell application "System Events" to set thePath to path of container of (path to me)`. `thePath` will contain the HFS path to the parent folder of the script.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, by default AppleScript will not understand a POSIX path, and you need to give it the full one, not a relative one.

```
osascript -e "display dialog \"Hey\" with icon POSIX file \"${PWD}/Icon.png\""
```

AppleScript requires double quotes and you need them surrounding the code so bash can interpret `${}`, which is why there are so many `\"`.

No need to convert your icon to `.icns`. AppleScript will gladly take your `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Events" to display dialog "{0}" with icon file (path of container of (path to me) & "Icon.png")
```

Worked for me. I had to save it in its own file, and I replaced the `{0}` with the message that needed to be in the dialog at runtime.