# How to get the full path of where my shell script is located

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am running a shell script on bash in linux. I want to the get absolute path to the parent directory of the folder where my script is located.

Following gives me the path to where my script is located

```
SCRIPTHOME="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
```

Thanks to the answer in following discussion:
[Reliable way for a Bash script to get the full path to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)

**Question:**
What should I change in `SCRIPTHOME="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"` to get the parent directory of the folder where my script is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `/..` after the cd. This assumes your script can never be in root, as that will still more or less "work", it just won't give you a parent directory (since there isn't one), it'll just give you `/`.

```
SCRIPTHOME="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")"/.. ; pwd -P )"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also add ../ before the command:

```
SCRIPTHOME="$( cd ../"$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
```