# Call a python file from bash script (.sh) file by providing absolute path

Tags: python, bash, absolute-path

I am calling a python file `result.py` from a script file `result.sh`. Both the files are present in different folders. How can I provide an absolute path?

My `result.sh` code:

```sh
if [[ $1 = "Census" ]]; then
    python -u result.py --model_name mlp --dataset census
```

Location of python file: `C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Python/result.py`

Location of script file: `F:/Script/result.sh`

Comment: Just put the absolute path of `result.py` in the script, what's the problem?

Comment: You may refer to the following post for absolute path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself

Comment: Is an absolute path really necessary in this case ? Why can't you just use the relative path `../Python/result.py` ?

Comment: Paths are relative to the user's directory, not the directory of the script.

Comment: It is part of big project which is executed on different machine

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the absolute path in the script:

```
if [[ $1 = "Census" ]]; then
    python -u C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Python/result.py \
        --model_name mlp \
        --dataset census \
```

Comment: I want to run my project on different machines.

Comment: You could use a configuration file to hold the location, or use an environment variable.