# Why is my file with bash functions not available within other scripts?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I have made a generic script for caching information as JSON to a specified file location. I've placed this function into a file called `~/Projects/tools/helpers/cache` and it reads as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cache-add() {
  local CACHE_FILE="$1"
  local CACHE_KEY="$2"
  local CACHE_VALUE="$3"

  if ! [[ -f "$CACHE_FILE" ]]; then
    touch $CACHE_FILE
    echo "{}" > $CACHE_FILE
  fi

  local next_cache=$(cat $CACHE_FILE | \
      jq \
      --arg cache_key "$CACHE_KEY" \
      --arg cache_value "$CACHE_VALUE" \
      '. * { ($cache_key) : $cache_value }')

  echo $next_cache > $CACHE_FILE
}
```

I'm attempting to source this file in my `.zshrc` and then access it via other scripts but it says `command not found` when used from other scripts. However the command works fine when I use it directly in my zsh session. Here is a sample of usage in a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CACHE_FILE=./.tools/cache.json

... some network request on cache miss ...

cache-add $CACHE_FILE "cache-key" "$api_result"

.. rest of script ...
```

within my `.zshrc` I'm sourcing the file as such:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source ${HOME}/Projects/tools/helpers/cache
```

When I run `cache-add` from terminal it works properly. When I run my script from the same zsh session it says command not found.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to source it into the individual script. Functions aren't exported by default, and when they _are_ exported it's shell-specific (so a function exported by bash can only be seen by bash scripts, a function exported by zsh can only be seen by zsh scripts, and _nothing_ can export a function in a way that guarantees a baseline sh shell can see it, since that's simply not a feature that the POSIX spec standardizes).

Comment: Remember, `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` are for **interactive** configuration. Scripts should never depend on them -- a script should be self-contained and be able to work correctly even if there's no interactive shell anywhere in its parent processes. (Think of scripts started directly from a GUI, a systemd user service, or the like).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot for that, very insightful and that solved it. I found this to get the path to the given script https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774063/845038 and then sourced the scripts within mine using that to base path them and it works!

Comment: As an aside, [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) Probably try https://shellcheck.net/ for details.