# Compilation error in fake script doesn't show specific failure in TeamCity build failure summary

Tags: teamcity, f#-fake, f#-fake-5

Using Fake 5.0 on TeamCity. Prior to 5.0 if there was a compilation error the error would be visible in the build failure summary. However now moving to 5.0 if there is an error the details in the summary are the generic output from Fake.

[image: TeamCity Error Summary]

In order to diagnose you have to then dig through the logs to find the compilation error.

This may not be specific to TeamCity because the same outputs are reported from the console.

Wondering if there is a configuration that I am missing either in the way that fake is being run or how the tasks are configured that needs to be set to allow the actual error to propagate up.

Running build script from TeamCity using bash:

```sh
%env.BashPath% build.sh run build.fsx
```

Bash script as per the getting started examples:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu
set -o pipefail

# liberated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18443300/433393
realpath() {
  OURPWD=$PWD
  cd "$(dirname "$1")"
  LINK=$(readlink "$(basename "$1")")
  while [ "$LINK" ]; do
    cd "$(dirname "$LINK")"
    LINK=$(readlink "$(basename "$1")")
  done
  REALPATH="$PWD/$(basename "$1")"
  cd "$OURPWD"
  echo "$REALPATH"
}

TOOL_PATH=$(realpath .fake)
FAKE="$TOOL_PATH"/fake

if ! [ -e "$FAKE" ]
then
  dotnet tool install fake-cli --tool-path $TOOL_PATH --version 5.*
fi
"$FAKE" "$@"
```

Running the MSBuild task:

```ml
Target.create "Build" (fun _ ->
  solutionFile
  |> MSBuild.build (fun p ->
        { p with
            ToolsVersion = Some "15.0"
            Verbosity = Some(Quiet)
            Targets = ["Build"]
            Properties = ["Optimize", "True"
                          "DebugSymbols", "True"
                          "Configuration", "Release"
                          "RunCodeAnalysis", "True"
                          "CodeAnalysisGenerateSuccessFile", "False"]
         }))
```