# bash equivalent of Python's os.path.normpath?

Tags: python, bash, path, find, normalization

What's the bash equivalent to [`os.path.normpath`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)? Specifically I'm interested in removing the leading `./` given when executing `find`.

```
matt@stanley:~/src/libtelnet-0.20/test$ find
.
./Makefile
./Makefile.in
./Makefile.am
...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?  `./foo` works fine, so programs shouldn't care...

Comment: `./Makefile` is not an absolute pathname, so you can use it without any issues. There. Problem solved.

Comment: @Nemo: The normalized paths are used in a manifest file. Otherwise it wouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for that, you can simply pipe the output through `sed`, you don't have to normalise the entire path:

```
your_command_goes_here | sed 's?^\./??'
```

That will get rid of all `./` sequences at the start of a line.

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax$ find -name 'qq*sh'
./qq.ksh
./qq.sh
./qq.zsh
./qq2.sh
./qq2.zsh
./qqq/qq.sh

pax$ find -name 'qq*sh' | sed 's?^./??'
qq.ksh
qq.sh
qq.zsh
qq2.sh
qq2.zsh
qqq/qq.sh
```

As you can see, I have a fairly intuitive naming standard for my temporary shell scripts :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to find a case where I'd want to use `os.path.normpath`. On a system that has symbolic links, such as unix or Windows, the value that it returns may not designate the same file:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/one /tmp/one/two
$ ln -s /tmp/one/two /tmp/foo
$ python -c 'import os.path; print os.path.normpath("/tmp/foo/..")'
/tmp
$ ls /tmp/foo/..
two
```

`/tmp/foo/..` is `/tmp/one`, not `/tmp`!

On Linux, `readlink -- "$filename"` normalizes all symbolic links in a path. The file name it returns designates the same file as `$filename` at the time the command is executed (it might not, later, if one of the symlinks involved is changed). But most of the time, that's not necessary: just keep `$filename` as it is.

If you want to remove a `./` prefix for cosmetic reasons, just strip it specifically.

```
filename=${filename#./}
find | sed -e 's!^\./!!'
```

Comment: The normalized paths are used in a manifest file. They cannot be absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this by using `find`'s `-printf` argument.

The following works fine if you're searching in multiple paths:

```
find path1 path2
```

The following works fine if you're searching in `.`:

```
find -printf '%P\n'
```

If you have a mixed paths (e.g. `find path1 path2 .`), you'd have to use `sed`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mixed paths it seems to work find without it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
newpath=`echo -n "$oldpath" | python -c 'import sys, os; print os.path.normpath(sys.stdin.readline())'`
```

?

I do not think there is any built-in bash function to do everything Python's `normpath` does.  You might be better off describing *exactly* what transformation you want to perform.

Comment: Pity print switches behaviour between 2 and 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Write something like this:

```
normpath() {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && return

    local skip=0 p o c

    p="$1"
    # check if we have absolute path and if not make it absolute
    [[ "${p:0:1}" != "/" ]] && p="$PWD/$p"

    o=""
    # loop on processing all path elements
    while [[ "$p" != "/" ]]; do
        # retrive current path element
        c="$(basename "$p")"
        # shink our path on one(current) element
        p="$(dirname "$p")"

        # basename/dirname correct handle multimple "/" chars
        # so we can not warry about them

        # skip elements "/./" 
        [[ "$c" == "." ]] && continue
        if [[ "$c" == ".." ]]; then
            # if we have point on parent dir, we must skip next element
            # in other words "a/abc/../c" must become "a/c"
            let "skip += 1"
        elif [[ 0 -lt $skip ]]; then
            # skip current element and decrease skip counter
            let "skip -= 1"
        else
            # this is normal element and we must add it to result
            [[ -n "$o" ]] && o="/$o"
            o="$c$o"
        fi
    done

    # last thing - restore original absolute path sign
    echo "/$o"
}
```

Comment: I have added some comments.

To make not absolute path "cleaning" we should change loop condition and add handle to situation when path go above it's starting point(add required count "../" elements)

Answer (score 1):

I found it: it's called `realpath`!
Type something like:

```
realpath ..   # the most interesting thing
```

or

```
realpath .    # equivalent to `pwd' and to `echo $PWD'
```

and enjoy!

Unlike `os.path.normpath`, `realpath` requires the path to exist. If you just want to normalise it as a string `realpath -m` can be used.

Comment: Would have been nice, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash). But if you are just interested in striping off leading ./ you could just do

```
find -type f | sed 's/^\.\///'
```

Comment: @Matt, funny, I had escaped it. But chosen some formatting > which did not show it properly. I choose pre formatting now and it shows