# Strip double dots from path in bash

Tags: regex, bash, path, sed

I wonder how  it would be possible to use a regular expression to simplify double dots from a file path (the path may not actually exist) ?

For example change `/my/path/to/.././my/./../../file.txt` into `/my/file.txt` or `path/./to/../../../file.txt` into `../file.txt`.

Is it possible to do this in one command in bash ? (using `sed` for example, not a  complicated python or perl script)

**edit**: I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash) but `realpath` isn't available on the computer I use.

**edit**:
From [F.J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505154/f-j) 's solution, I ended up building the following regex which works in more general cases (does not work if some folder of the path is named `....`):

```
sed -e 's|/\./|/|g' -e ':a' -e 's|\.\./\.\./|../..../|g' -e 's|^[^/]*/\.\.\/||' -e 't a' -e 's|/[^/]*/\.\.\/|/|' -e 't a' -e 's|\.\.\.\./|../|g' -e 't a'
```

Comment: Is the `realpath` command unavailable, or the [`realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) function?  If you have the function, an adequate program is: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600`
`#include <limits.h>`
`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <stdlib.h>`
`int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ int rc = 0; for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { char realname[_POSIX_PATH_MAX]; if (realpath(argv[i], realname) != 0) printf("%s\n", realname); else { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to evaluate realpath for %s\n", argv[i]); rc = 1; } } return(rc); }`

Comment: Only the `realpath` command is unavailable. However, I would like to use this inside a redistributable bash script, which makes this solution not very convenient. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -e 's|/\./|/|g' -e ':a' -e 's|/[^/]*/\.\./|/|' -e 't a'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '/my/path/to/.././my/./../../file.txt' |
  sed -e 's|/\./|/|g' -e ':a' -e 's|/[^/]*/\.\./|/|' -e 't a'
/my/file.txt
```

Here is a description of the approach:

```
read line
replace all '/\./' in line with '/'
while there is a match of '/[^/]*/\.\./' {
    replace first occurrence of '/[^/]*/\.\./' in line with '/'
}
output line
```

Comment: I endeed up using the following command which also works if the path should start with `../` : `sed -e 's|/\./|/|g' -e ':a' -e 's|/[^/]*/\.\./|/|' -e 't a' -e 's|^[^/]*/\.\./|../|'`. Thank you.

Comment: why doesn't this: `sed -e 's|/\./|/|g' -e ':a' -e 's|[^/]+/\.\./|/|' -e 't a'` work ?

Comment: @Mat It could be the `+`, try changing it to `\+`.

Comment: @Mat: The `+` notation is not understood by Standard (POSIX) `sed`.  Some (possibly many) versions of `sed` recognize an option `-r` to use extended regular expressions where `+` and `|` and so on are recognized.  Check the man page on your system.

Comment: The problem with you approach is that is ends up reducing `../../` to nothing. I proposed a solution in my question that prevents that.