# Get grandparent directory in bash script - rename files for a directory in their paths

Tags: linux, bash, path, centos, batch-rename

I have the following script, which I normally use when I get a bunch of files that need to be renamed to the directory name which contains them.

The problem now is I need to rename the file to the directory two levels up.  How can I get the grandparent directory to make this work?

With the following I get errors like this example:
"mv: cannot move `./48711/zoom/zoom.jpg` to `./48711/zoom/./48711/zoom.jpg`: No such file or directory".  This is running on CentOS 5.6.

I want the final file to be named: 48711.jpg

```
#!/bin/bash

function dirnametofilename() {
  for f in $*; do
    bn=$(basename "$f")
    ext="${bn##*.}"
    filepath=$(dirname "$f")
    dirname=$(basename "$filepath")
    mv "$f" "$filepath/$dirname.$ext"
  done
}

export -f dirnametofilename

find . -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'dirnametofilename "{}"'  \;

find .
```

Comment: Use two periods (`..`) to go up a directory, so `../../` for the grandparent directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note:

* **This answer solves the OP's *specific* problem**, in whose context "grandparent directory" means: the *parent* directory of the directory containing a file (it is the grandparent path from the *file's* perspective).

* By contrast, given the question's generic *title*, other answers here focus (only) on getting a *directory's* grandparent directory; the **succinct answer to the *generic* question is**: `grandParentDir=$(cd ../..; printf %s "$PWD")` to get the full path, and `grandParentDirName=$(cd ../..; basename -- "$PWD")` to get the dir. name only.</sup>

Try the following:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' \
  -execdir bash -c \
   'old="$1"; new="$(cd ..; basename -- "$PWD").${old##*.}"; echo mv "$old" "$new"' - {} \;
```

<sup>Note: `echo` was prepended to `mv` to be safe - remove it to perform the actual renaming.</sup>

- `-execdir ..\;` executes the specified command in the specific directory that contains a given matching file and expands `{}` to the filename of each.
- `bash -c` is used to execute a small ad-hoc script:

  - `$(cd ..; basename -- "$PWD")` determines the *parent* directory name of the directory containing the file, which is the *grandparent* path from the *file's* perspective.
  - `${old##*.}` is a Bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) that returns the input filename's suffix (extension).
  - Note how `{}` - the filename at hand - is passed as the *2nd* argument to the command in order to bind to `$1`, because `bash -c` uses the 1st one to set `$0` (which is set to dummy value `_` here).
- Note that each file is merely *renamed*, i.e., it *stays in its original directory*.

**Caveat**:

- Each directory with a matching file should only contain *1* matching file, otherwise multiple files will be renamed to the same target name in sequence - effectively, only the last file renamed will survive.

Answer (score 9):

Another method could be to use

```
(cd ../../; pwd)
```

If this were executed in any top-level paths such as `/`, `/usr/`, or `/usr/share/`, you would get a valid directory of `/`, but when you get one level deeper, you would start seeing results: `/usr/share/man/` would return `/usr`, `/my/super/deep/path/is/awesome/` would return `/my/super/deep/path`, and so on.

You could store this in a variable as well:

```
GRANDDADDY="$(cd ../../; pwd)"
```

and then use it for the rest of your script.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming filepath doesn't end in `/`, which it shouldn't if you use `dirname`, you can do

```
Parent = "${filepath%/*}"
Grandparent = "${filepath%/*/*}"
```

So do something like this

```
[[ "${filepath%/*/*}" == "" ]] && echo "Path isn't long enough" || echo "${filepath%/*/*}"
```

Also this likely won't work if you're using relative paths (like `find .`). In which case you will want to use

```
filepath=$(dirname "$f")
filepath=$(readlink -f "$filepath")
```

instead of

```
filepath=$(dirname "$f")
```

Also you're never stripping the extension, so there is no reason to get it from the file and then append it again.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `realpath ../../` or `readlink -f ../../` ? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284664/841108), [readlink(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html), [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html), [canonicalize_file_name(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/canonicalize_file_name.3.html), and [realpath(1)](http://www.man-online.org/page/1-realpath/). You may want to install the `realpath` package on Debian or Ubuntu. Probably CentOS has an equivalent package. (`readlink` should always be available, it is in [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/))