# How to check if two paths are equal in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

What's the best way to check if two paths are equal in Bash? For example, given the directory structure

```
~/
  Desktop/
    Downloads/ (symlink to ~/Downloads)
  Downloads/
    photo.png
```

and assuming that the current directory is the home directory, all of the following would be equivalent:

```
./                    and ~
~/Desktop             and /home/you/Desktop
./Downloads           and ~/Desktop/Downloads
./Downloads/photo.png and ~/Downloads/photo.png
```

Is there a native Bash way to do this?

Comment: Most of the answers (except mine) will break with bind mounts and things other than symlinks that can make two paths refer to the same thing.

Comment: Alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206973/how-to-find-out-whether-two-directories-point-to-the-same-location

Comment: re: @Ciro's links: [How do you normalize a file path in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284662) will help you check for path equality like asked, but doesn't handle bind-mounts if you want to actually check if 2 paths are the same file/directory on disk.  (Which is what the accepted answer here does.)  [How to find out whether two directories point to the same location](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206973) has answers that do that, but the current accepted one is just path canonicalization.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Bash's test commands have a `-ef` operator for this purpose:

```
if [[ ./ -ef ~ ]]; then ...

if [[ ~/Desktop -ef /home/you/Desktop ]]; then ...
```

Here is the documentation for this operator:

```
$ help test | grep -e -ef
      FILE1 -ef FILE2  True if file1 is a hard link to file2.
$ help '[['
[[ ... ]]: [[ expression ]]
    Execute conditional command.

    Returns a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional
    expression EXPRESSION.  Expressions are composed of the same primaries used
    by the `test' builtin, and may be combined using the following operators:

      ( EXPRESSION )    Returns the value of EXPRESSION
      ! EXPRESSION              True if EXPRESSION is false; else false
      EXPR1 && EXPR2    True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true; else false
      EXPR1 || EXPR2    True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true; else false

[...snip...]
```

Note that both paths of the operator have to refer to an existing file or directory for this to work. If the file or directory does not exist, the test will return false.

If you prefer, you can use the `test` or `[` builtins instead of double brackets:

```
if test ./ -ef ~; then ...

if [ ./ -ef ~ ]; then ...
```

but `[[ ... ]]` is preferred for consistency, since it encompasses the complete functionality of `test` and `[` in addition to other features, such as pattern matching and regex matching.

Comment: Nice! It looks like this method properly [compares device and inode numbers](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_test.htm) as well, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: `if [ ./ -ef ~ ]; then` should be enough, test is synonymous to `[`

Comment: Confirmed, it works across bind mounts, making my `find -samefile` answer obsolete.

Comment: It helped me with windows git bashrc path logical operator comparision for cd-ing. Thanks.

Comment: @geirha Can you please explain why you rolled back the previous edit? It added useful information and formatting fixes, as well as an important consistency fix - `[[` is emphatically  _not_ the same as `test`.

Comment: @tripleee, `[[` can do everything `[` can, and more. So for consistency, use `[[` for all string and file tests, rather than switching between `[` and `[[` in the same script.

Comment: I don't disagree, but the answer in its current form doesn't seem to suggest that.

Comment: @tripleee, how about now? Added part of `help [[` to make the connection between [[ and test more apparent

Comment: The first sentence still talks about `test` as if it was a synonym for `[[` but I guess this at least didn't make it worse. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `realpath`. For example:

```
realpath ~/file.txt
Result: /home/testing/file.txt

realpath ./file.txt
Result: /home/testing/file.txt
```

Also take a look at a similar answer here: [bash/fish command to print absolute path to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

Native bash way:

`pwd -P` returns the physical directory irrespective of symlinks.

```
cd "$dir1"
real1=$(pwd -P)
cd "$dir2"
real2=$(pwd -P)
# compare real1 with real2
```

Another way is to use `cd -P`, which will follow symlinks but leave you in the physical directory:

```
cd -P "$dir1"
real1=$(pwd)
cd -P "$dir2"
real2=$(pwd)
# compare real1 with real2
```

Comment: This only works for symlinks.  If the same filesystem is mounted at multiple points (e.g. `mount --bind /raid0/var-cache /var/cache`), then your best bet is to compare inodes.

Comment: This doesn't do quite what you want, since the first directory-change affects the interpretation of any relative path in the second one. To fix this, you should move the `cd` inside the command substitution (so it runs inside the subshell).

Comment: @ruakh makes an excellent point that I'd overlooked. geirha's answer is also quite interesting.

Answer (score 3):

If you have coreutils 8.15 or later installed, you have a `realpath` command that fully normalizes a path. It removes any `.` and `..` components, makes the path absolute, and resolves all symlinks. Thus:

```
if [ "$(realpath "$path1")" = "$(realpath "$path2")" ]; then
   echo "Same!"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Methods based on resolving symlinks fail when there are other factors involved.  For example, bind mounts.  (Like `mount --bind /raid0/var-cache /var/cache`

Using `find -samefile` is a good bet.  That will compare filesystem and inode number.

`-samefile` is a GNU extension.  Even on Linux, busybox find probably won't have it.  GNU userspace and Linux kernel often go together, but you can have either without the other, and this question is only tagged Linux and bash.)

```
# params: two paths.  returns true if they both refer to the same file
samepath() {
    # test if find prints anything
    [[ -s "$(find -L "$1" -samefile "$2")" ]]  # as the last command inside the {}, its exit status is the function return value
}
```

---

e.g. on my system:

```
$ find /var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb  -samefile /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
/var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb


$ stat {/var/tmp/EXP,/var}/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  File: ‘/var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb’
...
Device: 97ch/2428d      Inode: 2147747863  Links: 1
...

  File: ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb’
Device: 97ch/2428d      Inode: 2147747863  Links: 1
```

You can use `find -L` for cases where you want to follow symlinks in the final path component:

```
$ ln -s   /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb foo
$ find    /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb  -samefile foo
$ find -L /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb  -samefile foo
/var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Obviously this works for paths which refer to directories or any type of file, not just regular files.  They all have inode numbers.

---

usage:

```
$ samepath /var/cache/apt/  /var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/  && echo true
true
$ ln -sf /var/cache/apt foobar
$ samepath foobar /var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/  && echo true
true
samepath /var/tmp/EXP/cache/apt/ foobar   && echo true
true
samepath foobar   && echo true   # doesn't return true when find has an error, since the find output is empty.
find: `': No such file or directory
```

So `find -L` dereferences symlinks for `-samefile`, as well as for the list of paths.  So either or both can be symlinks.

Comment: +1. Could you add some information about portability, though? (It doesn't look like `-samefile` is specified by POSIX?)

Comment: @ruakh: oh right, it's a GNU extension, probably only found in GNU `find`.  Obviously `bash` doesn't come with GNU find, but I think the `linux` tag made me leave out a mention of this.