# Bash: eliminating redundant path components?

Tags: linux, bash, path, sh

How can I eliminate redundant components in a path?

For example, I would like to transform

```
/foo/../foo/bar
```

to

```
/foo/bar
```

Comment: See [How do you normalize a file path in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/284662/4154375).

Comment: Note that on Unix-like systems that support symbolic links, '/X/../Y' is not always the same as '/Y'.  In the example in this question, if you have directories '/bar/foo/bar' and '/bar/qux/bar', and '/foo' is a symlink to '/bar/qux', then '/foo/../foo/bar' is actually '/bar/foo/bar' and '/foo/bar' is actually '/bar/qux/bar'.  All attempted solutions that just do textual substitutions on paths are wrong.  (But it is ok to do that kind of thing on Windows because '..' means something different there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [gnu `realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html):

```
p='/foo/../foo/bar'

realpath -m "$p"
```

**Output:**

```
/foo/bar
```

As per `realpath --help`:

```
-m, --canonicalize-missing   no components of the path need exist
```

---

You can also use more commonly available `readlink` (thanks to @pjh):

```
readlink -m "$p"
```

Comment: This answer is good, but note that `readlink` does the same thing and is more commonly available.

Comment: Thanks @pjh, I have added it in my answer.

Comment: If you use `-m` option as I suggested then it won't check for existence of path/link

Answer (score 0):

You might pipe through something like: sed 's-/../foo/-/-g' to replace up/down reference in path names.