# Plan - Pass a var-file in a different directory to plan

Tags: terraform

Using Terraform v0.11.11, when invoking terraform plan, supply a .tfvars file that is NOT in the current directory e.g a common 'global' file for global constants

seems to just ignore it when I try ../ in an var-file option

```
-var-file="../$(ENV).global.tfvars"
```

What options do I have to achieve a similar result if this is not possible (event in the v0.12 is this still the case)?

Comment: what does your variables file look like - if the format is wrong TF will not pick it up: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12551

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Formats are fine since I copied the exact .tfvars files into the 'current' directory as well to test and it worked.  When I tried to reference them with a relative path (e.g for parent dir -var-file="../xxxxx.tfvars) it didnt.  So I assumed maybe relative paths dont work for -var-file?  is this true / do you know of another way.  Essentially Im trying to get around repetitively copying global var file around to each modules.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are on linux you could use $(realpath ../$(ENV).global.tfvars) to return the absolute path of the file. try it out.

Comment: I used symlinks successfully for this scenario

Comment: awesome - realpath worked cheers!

Comment: or readlink: https://stackoverflow.com/a/284671/299421